# SQL - Default Value of other columns/fields

Tags: sql, triggers, default

I have an Access DB that contains the following column/fields: [ID], [itemCode], [imageCode].

The fileCode is "computed" expression of:

```
[itemCode] & "IMG" & [ID] & ".jpg"
```

So that if [ID] and [itemCode] are "4" and "item008a" (respectively) then the [imageCode] will be:
"item008aIMG4.jpg".

However, I am migrating to SQL, and while rebuilding the table, I found you can't do this with the column's default value or computed formula.

I've read triggers would be the best resolve, but have only written triggers that affect other tables and not itself (if that is even possible?).

Is there something more direct? If not, what would the trigger look like?

Any help most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can use computed column in SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as computed column

```
ALTER  Table TableA ADD    imageCode    
AS cast(itemCode as varchar(10))
+ 'IMG' + cast( id as varchar(10))
+ '.jpg'
```

Comment: beat me to the punch :)  Here is a working SQL Fiddle demoing the computed column. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/966af/1

Comment: Thank you. I ran the query in SQL Management Studio and it works like a charm. Looking at the "computed column spec" in the design view, the formula reads: (((CONVERT([varchar](20),[devCode],0)+'IMG')+CONVERT([varchar](max),[ID],0))+'.jpg')